# Creating custom file searches with RegEx through file recovery program

Tags: regex

Hi I'm looking to add custom file extensions using Active@ File Recovery and editing their Signature_template file using what they refer to as the RegEx language. I have no idea how to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The file types I'm looking to add are .mts, .txt, .psd, .ttf, .otf and Adobe Premiere project files with extensions like .prproj, .plb, .ppj, and .prel

Here's the Signature_Template file that comes with File Recovery: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZeS2JhxZMfo33AwD2ZHSmrlfqPwfJmHkZjdyP1nsyJA/edit?usp=sharing

There's a few searches already there but I can't make heads or tails of it or figure out just how to go about looking up the files I mentioned above.

If you need any additional info, just let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a different file recovery program (R-Studio) that recognized the file extensions we were looking for. Worked pretty well and we got a lot of stuff off the deleted partition.